Why does Nginx reverse proxy return a 404 status code?
I’m struggling with a problem while configuring an Nginx reverse proxy server. Everything seems fine, but I keep receiving a 404 error.
I’ve never done this before and don’t have experience with such configuration
What I expect is that when I go to custom.domain.com, I’ll see the content of https://frontend.example.com without the URI changing in the browser (stealth forwarding).
I'm setting up an Nginx reverse proxy server on Coolify.
The server is configured to redirect traffic from my custom domain custom.domain.com to a frontend application which is at https://frontend.example.com.
Here's what I've done:

Created a new domain custom.domain.com on CloudFlare
Created a CNAME DNS record for custom.domain.com pointing to my ginx server (proxy.example-host.com)
Set up an SSL origin certificate from Cloudflare for the custom
domain and added it to my Nginx configuration.

The Nginx server works perfectly if I visit https://proxy.example-host.com, correctly serving the frontend application. But when I try to access custom.domain.com I get a 404 Not Found error.
Here's the relevant part of my config file:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name custom.domain.com;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name custom.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/cloudflare/origin.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cloudflare/origin.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://frontend.example.com/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_name frontend.example.com;
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    }
}


The 404 might come from your nginx, or from frontend.example.com. Check and see if your nginx logs provide more information about the source of this server error. A first glance your config looks more or less OK. Also check if you can successfully query frontend.example.com from your server, i.e. manually with for example curl -v https://frontend.example.com

@HBruijn, everything looks correct. My frontend app is working fine, and I don’t see any logs from nginx when I visit custom.domain.com.
Also, when I ping custom.domain.com, I see that my proxy is actually being pinged, so that also seems correct.
However, I keep receiving a 404 error, and I don’t know why...
